# How is char(*)[20] different from char(*Object::variable)[20]?

Tags: c++, arrays

I've created an object that takes a multidimensional array (a grid) as an argument (`char grid[][20]`), as well as a vector of those objects (to which it will belong).

The constructor assigns the member variable `char (*my_grid)[20]` to the argument, so that the object functions can change the original grid. This already works - I can assign `my_grid[x][y]` to different values, and it changes the original 'grid'.

I want to create a member function that creates another new object (from within the original object), passing 'my_grid' as the argument (the new object will be added to the original vector of objects).

However, the compiler says that `my_grid` is a `char(*Object::my_grid)[20]` when what I need is a 
`char(*)[20]`. I don't understand the difference. How do I pass the grid as an argument in the object member function, to create a new object? Thanks.

Object has member variable: char(*my_grid)[20];

Constructor:

```
Object::Object(char the_grid[][20], vector<Object>& the_objects)  
{  
    my_grid = the_grid;  
    my_objects = &the_objects;  
}
```

Object Member Function:

```
void Object::new_object()  
{  
    Object second_object(my_grid, my_objects);  //this doesn't work
}
```

Comment: You may edit your question instead of putting code in comment.

Comment: You are making something up. If the member variable `my_grid` is indeed declared as  `char (*my_grid)[20]`, then the code will not produce the error you quoted (unless your compiler is broken). A very similar error will pop up if you attempt this: `Object second_object(&Object::my_grid, my_objects);`, but your code does not look that way.

Comment: I get the error: No instance of constructor "Object::Object" matches the argument list. Argument types are (char(*)[20]... etc. I can't see where I'd be making anything up. Thanks.

Comment: @hassapikos: Well, a simple sample code that copies what you posted so far about `my_grid` compiles without any errors. However, there's a problem with the second argument (see my answer).

Comment: You made a vector for your objects, why not the grid too :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious error in your code is actually related to the *second* constructor argument. Inside `Object::new_object()` you attempt to pass `my_objects` to the constructor, which implies that `my_objects` has type `vector<Object>&` or `vector<Object>`. However, inside the constructor you initialize `my_objects` with `&the_objects`, which implies that `my_objects` has type `vector<Object> *`. This is self-contradictory.

So, what is the declared type of `my_objects`?

However, in any case this is a problem with the second argument of your constructor. The error message you quoted refers to the first argument and `my_grid` member. The error message makes no sense in the context of the code you posted so far. There's no such error there. Either your compiler is broken, you are posting fake code or you are misquoting the error message.

In any case, try fixing the problem with the second argument and see it it helps.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right - when I delete all the vector references, the 'my_grid' argument does not generate any errors, for some reason. My member variable for storing the vector was a pointer 'vector<Object> *my_objects'. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`char (*something)[20]` would be just a regular pointer to a character array.

`char (*Object::something)[20]` is a *pointer-to-member* type.

This is a type that says "If we have an `Object`, then it will have a member variable of type `char[20]` at this location."  Its usage is like so:

```
class Object
{
public:
  int a;
  char b[20];
};

/* ... */

//Acquire the location of 'b' relative to any 'Object'
char (*Object::myPtrToMemberB)[20] = &Object::b;
int (*Object::myPtrToMemberA) = &Object::a;

Object x;
//Access member 'b' via ptr to member
x.*myPtrToMemberB[0] = 'b';

//Access member 'a' via ptr to member
x.*myPtrToMemberA = 127;
```

Comment: Note, this is only to explain the difference between the two types you listed in the title.

Comment: Is it possible to convert a 'pointer_to_member' type to a regular pointer, within an object member function? (I have edited the original query). Thanks.

Comment: @hassapikos it -is- possible, but it would be a bit out of scope for what you're actually looking for.  I didn't have the time to make any more responses, but it looks like AndreyT has you covered!